# Change of Measure - Radon Nikodym

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I always found the change of measure as given by :

The radon nikodym derivative with $Q$ and $P$ the probability measures :

$$Z=\frac{dQ}{dP}$$

The change of measure :

$$E^P[X]=E^Q[XZ]$$

My question is : If I have to compute a conditional expectation instead, would this be true ? :

$$E^P \left[ X|F(s) \right] = E^Q[XZ(s)|F(s)]$$

If it is, how can I get this formula from the first one? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No… you have to use the [Bayes formula for conditional expectations](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/10689/bayes-rule-for-conditional-expectations-proof-review).

You also find the proof of it as an answer if you follow the link.